# Consultar linha da tabela por nome de coluna no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

No Laravel estou querendo consultar um registro no banco de dados pelo `id` da tabela, porém o código abaixo só consulta se a nomenclatura da coluna for `id`

```
$prod = $this->produto->find(3)
```

Se o nome da coluna é `prod_id` por exemplo, como posso retornar o registro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Produto::where('prod_id',123)->get();
```

ou

```
Produto::where('prod_id',123)->first();
```

Onde `Produto` é a classe do Modelo

**Atualização**

O Laravel por padrão usa a coluna `id` como id dos seus Models, para alterar isso e poder usar `prod_id` na função `find()` você precisa 
alterar o seu Model da seguinte forma:

```
class Produto extends Eloquent {

    protected $primaryKey = 'prod_id';

}
```

Comment: Vlw, era isso que eu precisava

Comment: @IvanAlves pf coloque como resposta correcta